# Table of contents spills onto further content

Tags: html, syntax, markdown

I am trying to create a table of contents for my markdown file, however I have an issue with it spilling onto the rest of the content on the page.

[image: table of content error]

You can see in the above picture that a section is missing and the image has moved up.
I isolated the problem area to this section:

```
<!-- CONTENTS -->
<details open="open">
  <summary>Table of Contents</summary>
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#Objective">Objective / Goal of the Game</a></li>
    <li><a href="#resources">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#board-layout">Board Layout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#upgrades">Upgrades</a></li>
    <li><a href="#turn-structure">Turn Structure</a></li>
    <li><a href="#trade">Trade</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bankruptcy">Bankruptcy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tips>Tips</a></li>
  </ol>
</details>

<!--OBJECTIVE-->
## Objective, Goal of the Game.

The winner in Back from the Brink is whichever Player has the most fully improved conservation areas by the end of the turn limit, or is the last player still in the game.

If the number of conservation areas is tied at the end of the game, whoever has the most money is crowned the winner.
<!--Resources-->
## Resources

Their are two types of resources in "Back from the Brink".

1. Money (£) - used for purchasing and improving conservation areas.
2. Upgrade Points (UP) - used for purchasing player upgrades.

<!--board-layout-->
## Board Layout

See here a layout of the board (for visually reference)

<p align="center">
    <img src="images/htpboardlayout.png" alt="board layout">
</p>

As you can see their are several types of board tiles:

* **Conservation Area Tile** – This is an endangered species habitat. If unowned, a player can **buy the Conservation Area** for money. If a user other than the user who bought the tile lands on it, they will have to **pay a ticket fee** to see the animals. This fee is payed directly to the **owner of the Conservation Area**. This ticket fee increases as the Conservation Area is improved. Each **Conservation Area** belongs to a **Continent**. You must own all Conservation Areas in a **Continent** in order to improve the **Conservation Areas**.
```

The image becomes hyperlinked somehow and provides the url:

```
https://github.com/.../#tips%3ETips%3C/a%3E%3C/li%3E%20%20%3C/ol%3E%3C/details%3E%3C!--OBJECTIVE--%3E%3Ch2%3EObjective,%20Goal%20of%20the%20Game.%3C/h2%3E%3Cp%3EThe%20winner%20in%20Back%20from%20the%20Brink%20is%20whichever%20Player%20has%20the%20most%20fully%20improved%20conservation%20areas%20by%20the%20end%20of%20the%20turn%20limit,%20or%20is%20the%20last%20player%20still%20in%20the%20game.%3C/p%3E%3Cp%3EIf%20the%20number%20of%20conservation%20areas%20is%20tied%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20game,%20whoever%20has%20the%20most%20money%20is%20crowned%20the%20winner.%3C/p%3E%3C!--Resources--%3E%3Ch2%3EResources%3C/h2%3E%3Cp%3ETheir%20are%20two%20types%20of%20resources%20in%20%22Back%20from%20the%20Brink%22.%3C/p%3E%3Col%3E%3Cli%3EMoney%20(%C2%A3)%20-%20used%20for%20purchasing%20and%20improving%20conservation%20areas.%3C/li%3E%3Cli%3EUpgrade%20Points%20(UP)%20-%20used%20for%20purchasing%20player%20upgrades.%3C/li%3E%3C/ol%3E%3C!--board-layout--%3E%3Ch2%3EBoard%20Layout%3C/h2%3E%3Cp%3ESee%20here%20a%20layout%20of%20the%20board%20(for%20visually%20reference)%3C/p%3E%3Cp%20align=
```

I am convinced I haven't closed an HTML structure but I can't seem to pinpoint where it is.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking (how are we supposed to know what you _want_ this to look like so we can understand that "a section is misisng and the image has moved up"?), but there's a quoting issue that SO's syntax highlighting makes pretty clear. Your `<li><a href="#tips>Tips</a></li>` is missing a closing quote on the `href`.

Comment: Definitely a quote missing.